# what role does OSB play in terms of security

Tags: ws-security, osb

I would like to know whether OSB plays a crucial role in terms of security apart from just behaving as a middle-ware.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.  You realize that OSB is a server that you develop services with.  Those services are supposed to be called from OSB using some form of a proxy service URL (http://localhost:8001/MyService?wsdl), so if you don't think you need to secure that endpoint from 3rd parties calling it, that's entirely up to you.  You can use all of the OWSM security features that come with a regular WLS server, so I don't know why you would think OSB would be any different than any other WLS-based server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inbound Security:**

Inbound security ensures that Oracle Service Bus proxy services handle only the requests that come from authorized clients. (By default, any anonymous or authenticated user can connect to a proxy service.) It can also ensure that no unauthorized user has viewed or modified the data as it was sent from the client.

You set up inbound security when you create proxy services and you can modify it as your needs change. For outward-facing proxy services (which receive requests from service consumers), consider setting up strict security requirements such as two-way SSL over HTTPS. For proxy services that are guaranteed to receive requests only from other Oracle Service Bus proxy services, you can use less secure protocols.

For each proxy service, you can configure the following inbound security checks:

Transport-level security applies security checks as part of establishing a connection between a client and a proxy service. The security requirements that you can impose through transport-level security depend on the protocol that you configure the proxy service to use.

For example, for proxy services that communicate over the HTTP protocol, you can require that all clients authenticate against a database of users that you create in the Security Configuration module of the Oracle Service Bus Administration Console. You then create an access control policy that specifies conditions under which authenticated users are authorized to access the proxy service.

Custom Authentication for message-level security. Oracle Service Bus supports client-specified custom authentication credentials for inbound transport- and message-level requests. The custom authentication credentials can be in the form of a custom token, or a username and password.

Message-level security (for proxy services that are Web Services) is part of the WS-Security specification. It applies security checks before processing a SOAP message or specific parts of a SOAP message.

**Outbound Security**

Outbound security secures communication between a proxy service and a business service. Most of the tasks that you complete for outbound security are for configuring proxy services to comply with the transport-level or message-level security requirements that business services specify.

For example, if a business service requires user name and password tokens, you create a service account, which either directly contains the user name and password, passes along the user name and password that was contained in the inbound request, or provides a user name and password that depend on the user name that was contained in the inbound request. For more information, see Section 2.1.15, "Creating Service Account Resources."

If a business service requires the use of PKI technology for digital signatures, or SSL authentication, you create a service key provider, which provides private keys paired with certificates. For more information, see "Service Key Providers" in the Oracle Fusion Middleware Administrator's Guide for Oracle Service Bus.

**More info (Oracle Official Documentation):
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/dev.1111/e15866/model.htm#OSBDV1476**